# No background color on icon link

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, icons, font-awesome

I'm using AdminLTE 3 theme with font awesome icons as a links to actions:

```
<a href="/products/2/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Rendered page looks good, icon background is transparent.
When I hover mouse on icon I get black background around the icon.

How to remove this black background?

I've tried this but nothing happened:

```
i, a :hover{
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: try `i:hover, a:hover` (note :hover after both i and a and no space in between). if that doesn't work, then you may need something more specific than what is causing the background colour

Comment: font awesome is font base and you can't change background. instead use svg icon.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] of your current problem as with font-awesome 4.7, you wouldn't get any background on hover: https://jsfiddle.net/qbnjsoc0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one resolved problem:

```
i:hover, a:hover {
    background: transparent!important; // or background-color
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: I would try not to use `!important` - it should only be used as a last resort - especially as you are applying it to a bare element selector.  If you use it like this, it will most likely cause you issues further down the line

Comment: So far I used important! until I don't get other solution or find what piece of css is making me noise with this black background

Comment: right click inspect element - see what rule is causing the background and override it. if you use important like this, you will need to use it on other rules to overide this one and then you will get to a point where your code is an unmaintainable nightmare where trying to remove the background colour from a hovered link will be impossible (and your stylesheet will be bloated and reduce the speed of your page)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
a i{
  padding:10px;
  background:#fcf;
}
a:hover,i:hover{
  
  background:transparent;
  /* or */
  /* background:none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<a href="/products/2/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

Comment: This one doesn't works, probably as Pete said something deeper is declaring background code, so I used important! so far

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that some style rule for all links is overriding this one. Maybe try this:

```
i:hover, a:hover {
    background: transparent!important; // or background-color
}
```